# How can I use a "String" to compare an "if" and "if else" statement?

Tags: string, methods, int, call

The below code works just fine. But how can I get the user to input a string instead of and int to bring up either the "shop" or "inn" method?

ie. When "int a = navigate.nextInt();" is changed to "String a = navigate.nextString();" and the "if" and "if else" conditions are changed to "a == "shop" or "inn". The next line to run the correct method does nothing.

(I hope that made sense, see below)

```
import java.util.*;
public class ShopTest {

public static Scanner navigate = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Where to?\n Shop (1)\n  Inn (2)");
    int a = navigate.nextInt();

        if (a == 1) 
            Shop();
        else if (a == 2) 
            Inn();
    }

public static void Shop() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to my shop\nWould you like to see my wares?");

}

public static void Inn() {
    System.out.println("**You enter the inn and approach the barkeep**\nHow can I help you?");

}
```

}

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java - and just for the sake of it, use `#nextLine`, as `#nextString` is not a method supported by `Scanner`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("Where to?\n Shop \n  Inn ");
        String a = navigate.nextLine();

            if (a.equals("Shop")) 
                Shop();
            else if (a.equals("Inn")) 
                Inn();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .equal

- `==`  tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).
- .equal tests for value equality (whether they are logically 
  "equal").

More:  [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)